# How to create only new tables in persistence.xml using JPA with Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence.xml

My `persistence.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primary">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/LMSDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer"
                value="allow" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

If I start my application the tables are created, because `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is set to `create`. If I add new entities to my application, I don't want the existing data in my database to get lost, but I want to keep it and only create new tables.

How is that possible?

Comment: You should use `update`. Also take a look to this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1689769/4536811

Comment: Write out the neccessary schema changes: Look this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775419/log-sql-from-hibernate-if-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-update/49776600#49776600

Answer (score 1):

As of today, this is **not** possible using Hibernate versions `<= 5.2.x` (JPA 2.0/2.1). By design (default), you have these options available, see [official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl):

- `create` - Create the associated schema from scratch.
- `update` - Updates an existing schema.
- `validate` - Validates if the JPA annotated model classes comply with an existing schema.
- `create-drop` - Create the schema and automatically drops it when the JVM is terminated.

For further reference see an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/438146/2849346) on this topic.

Maybe it's worth looking into [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) which gives you better capabilities to manage schema migration and upgrade paths. Vlad Mihalcea has written a [good blog post](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-integration-testing-strategies/) on this topic as well.